# How to convert a Curl to PHP CURL

Tags: php-curl

I'm trying to convert this curl command into php:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" \
-d '{"image": "ubuntu-16.04"}' \
https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/servers/42/actions/rebuild
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Really? There is even one site doing this for you. And it's the first hit on Google for convert curl to php...

https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Comment: Yes I searching and test  code and view other topic but  return error from hetzner 
{ "error": { "message": "404 Not Found", "code": "not_found", "details": null } }

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) tool to generate PHP-CURL using curl command parameters.

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/servers/42/actions/rebuild');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"image\": \"ubuntu-16.04\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: _ENV["Bearer API_TOKEN"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: I tested  your code but returned error from hetzner :
```
{ "error": { "message": "404 Not Found", "code": "not_found", "details": null } }
```

Comment: 404 error not related to generated code. Just use the tools and check your parameters.